# Constructing an Object with Nested Tables Inside It

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have an object which contains some nested tables and I'd like to construct it using just a single select statement. My types look like the following.

```
create or replace type number_table as table of number;
/
create or replace type multiple_tables as object
(
  num_table1 number_table,
  num_table2 number_table
)
```

And the following shows basically what I'd like to do, again ideally in just a single sql statement to avoid context switching.

```
select multiple_tables(number_table
                       (select tblB.purchaseID from table_purchases tblB where tblB.customerID = tblA.customerID),
                       number_table
                       (select tblC.paymentID from table_payments tblC where tblC.customerID = tblA.customerID))
  from table_customer
 where table_customer.customerName = 'John Smith';
```

(The specific error for this is "ORA-00936: missing expression" in case anyone was wondering)

Essentially, is it possible to construct a nested table from within another select statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`CAST`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions016.htm) and [`MULTISET`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators006.htm) operators:

```
WITH table_A ( value ) AS (
  SELECT LEVEL
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL < 5
),
table_B ( id ) AS (
  SELECT 2*LEVEL
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL < 4
)
SELECT  multiple_tables(
          CAST(
            MULTISET (
              SELECT * FROM table_a
            )
            AS number_table
          ),
          CAST(
            MULTISET (
              SELECT * FROM table_b
            )
            AS number_table
          )
        ) AS multi_tables
FROM    DUAL;
```

**Outputs**:

```
MULTI_TABLES
----------------------------------------------------------
MULTIPLE_TABLES(NUMBER_TABLE(1,2,3,4),NUMBER_TABLE(2,4,6))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `CAST MULTISET` to extract the data as you want; the structure of the query  should be like this:

```
select multiple_tables(
       cast (multiset (select 1 from dual connect by level < 10 ) as number_table ),
       cast (multiset (select 1 from dual connect by level < 10 ) as number_table )
       )
from dual
```